# Export 3D Mesh without shading issues

Tags: graphics3d, export, complex, mesh

I can export a mesh to a .obj file such as with the following:

```
a1 = ComplexPlot3D[Zeta[z], {z, 0 - 40 I, 2 + 40 I}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 15}, PlotPoints -> 200, Mesh -> 10, 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 80, 15}]
Export["a1.obj", a1]
```

When I import it into an external program, I get a mesh that looks like this:

[image]

It seems to have some really bad shading problem. The points on the mesh don't look very nice, and I think that's leading to the issue. Here's a video showing the shading and the points of the mesh in more detail: https://youtu.be/X6ocfyqWsA0

Is there any way to export a mesh that doesn't have such terrible shading problems (perhaps making the points more uniformly spaced would help)? Any ideas here?

Comment: It looks like there are triangles on top of each other and the depth test in your external program (C4D?) doesn't have the z-buffer resolution to prevent what's called [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) - a rasterization problem - or the normal vectors are not well defined at these points or susceptible to floating point 'noise' because the triangles are too thin / degenerate. Having seen your video I think it's the latter.

Comment: @flinty, you're right, I'm sure it is one of those two problems, and I'm assuming that could be fixed if Mathematica could generate the points of the mesh differently. Is that possible?

Comment: `PlotPoints` can take a list like `PlotPoints -> {25, 100}`. That will have more points in one direction compared to the other and might avoid some of the ultra-thin degenerate triangles that cause the problem.